# Как правильно удалять пользовательские комментарии Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

У меня есть сайт, который я сейчас делаю, и там есть такая тема:
Если пользователь оставил комментарий, то я хочу дать ему права удалить свой же комментарий. Я создаю ActiveForm, и делаю в ней только SubmitButton, которой даю параметр value равным id этого комментария.

Вот как это выглядит во view

```
<?php if(Yii::$app->user->identity->id == $photo->user->id || Yii::$app->user->identity->id == $comment->user->id): ?>
    <?php ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Удалить', ['name' => 'DeleteComment', 'value' => $comment->id, 'class' => 'btn btn-link']) ?>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Мне стало интересно, я перешел в Instagram, посмотреть как там удаляются комментарии, и увидел, что комментарий можно удалить без формы. 
Есть кнопка крестика, которая отвечает за удаление, захожу в ее код, и вижу картину:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, просто кнопка, без формы типа GET, POST, не задается параметра id как у меня. Как тогда происходит удаление комментария в Instagram, и как лучше реализовать его мне? Может я зря создаю форму? Просто лучше практики не знаю, буду очень рад помощи

Answer (score 0):

```
Я реализовывал типа стены* через виджет
```

во вью

```
 echo Html::a('<i class="icon">delete</i> <span>Удалить</span>', ['/my-page'], [
                            'data' => [
                                'method' => 'post',
                                'confirm' => 'Вы уверены?',
                                'params' => ['delWall' => true, 'id' => $wall->id],
                            ]
                        ]);
```

а принимает метод `run()` ну там я проверяю параметр delWall проверяю права и вызваю метод удаления